# How to shift a row in Excel table when data is added via formula?

Tags: excel

I am currently doing an audit of software installed on workstations and servers, using an excel sheet to keep track of everything.
In this sheet there are two tables. Table 1 contains all devices and all the software installed on them; this table currently has ~12,000 records in it.
Table 2 has a list of the unique software, as well as columns depicting what kind of software it is and any notes associated with it. Table 2 pulls the information from Table 1 using the formula `=SORT(UNIQUE(SOFTWARE))`.

The problem I face is that when a device gets added to Table 1, and they have software not installed on any other devices, rather than inserting that software into Table 2 with a blank row it shifts the column down but does not adjust the other columns so I end up with information against the wrong piece of software.

I've tried remedying this by making Table 2 an actual Excel table and moving the sort unique formula to a different sheet. Table 2 then just simply pulls that information into column A. Apparently this is meant to shift the row when new info is added but no such luck. Ideally, I don't want to have to manually go through and adjust all the information as that will become increasingly time consuming as more data is added.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can just make Excel shift the whole row rather than just the column when pulling new data in?

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the other columns hand entered or are they entered with a different formula?

Comment: The other columns are hand entered, it's just the software column that's got a formula

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest that you try `=UNIQUE(Table2SoftwareRange, SORT(Table1SoftwareRange))` instead but couldn't get that to work.

So... instead, I recommend that you replace your mechanism to keep the two in sync with something else. Unfortunately, the two ways I can think of require manual steps unless you use VBA.

## Quick & Dirty

For example, if your first table had a hidden column that displayed the software name if it did not appear in the second table, Then you could make a formula using `TEXTJOIN` that tells you what software rows you need to add in the second table. Then you could manually add the missing rows and sort.

## Power-Query

Another option is Power Query, but for your needs you would need to make a query that imports its own output, adds missing software, and sorts.

If...

1. your installs table is actually a table (highlight it and click "insert table" if not) with a table name (changeable in "Table" ribbon that only appears if cursor is in a table) of "Table1" and the column containing the software name is titled "Software", and
2. your software table is actually a table with a table name of "Table2" and the column containing the software name is titled "Software"

then you'd create a query, using **Data - Get Data - From Other Sources - Blank Query**, click Advanced Editor, and enter the following...

```
let
  // Load the Installs table
  Installs = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  // Remove all columns except "Software"
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Installs,{”Software"}),
  // Remove duplicates
  #"Installed Software" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
  // Load the table of known software
  Software = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
  // Merge the installed software and the known software together
  #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Installed Software", {”Software"}, Software, {”Software"}, "SoftwareTable", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
  // Get a list of all columns we want except "Software"
  ColumnNamesToExpand = List.RemoveItems(
    Table.ColumnNames(Software),
    {”Software"}
  ),
  #"Expanded SoftwareTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    #"Merged Queries",
    "SoftwareTable",
    ColumnNamesToExpand,
    ColumnNamesToExpand
  ),
  #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded SoftwareTable", {{"Software", Order.Ascending}})
in
  #"Sorted Rows"
```

then rename that query to "Software" and close & load it to a new sheet. This gives you what you want except that it's pure output; any changes will be overwritten every time you refresh it! But that output table should now be in your workbook with the table name the same as your query name ("Software"), so we can change your query to read itself instead of Table2. Edit that query again, go into the advanced editor, replace `"Table2"` with `"Software"`, and now your new Software table will do what you want every time you refresh it.

(Once you have this, completely delete your original Table2. It's just confusing and outdated duplicate data at this point.)

I know that I just gave you a whole lot of code that will feel alien if you are not familiar with power query. **Don't be discouraged! Power query is amazing** if you occasionally need to take data and manipulate it. There is so much you can do with it. You can unpivot, pull data in from other workbooks and other sources, and so much more. Most of the time you don't even need to type code and can instead just click around to do what you need. Also, this query is ugly, not because of what it does but because I gave you everything in a *single* query! Normally I'd break this up into several different queries that reference each other. (Queries can be referred by other queries by name, like global variables, allowing you to make each query simple and easier to understand/maintain, building upon others.)

One drawback is that refreshing is not automatic. You either need to

1. Right-click on the Software table and click "Refresh",
2. From the ribbon, click **Data - Refresh All**,
3. Write VBA to do this for you automatically every time the table of installs is modified.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful response! I assumed there was a way to do this using VBA but was unsure on how to do that myself.
I've gone through and ensured the column names are Software now, they were display name previously, but when I add the query however, I'm getting an invalid identifier regarding "Software" for the table.SelectedColumns line. Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue I previously mentioned, however am now getting an "expression error: The import Table.SelectedColumns matches no exports. Did you miss a reference?" and then when I go to the error I get "Expression.Error: The name 'Table.SelectedColumns' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.".

Comment: Oops! Sorry, it's SelectColumns, not SelectedColumns. Fixed. I highly recommend https://www.powerquery.io/ as a reference for coding. It has less detail but it's so much cleaner and easier to navigate than Microsoft's documentation.